# Android Room Fetch data with dynamic table name

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

Is it possible to `fetch data` by passing the `table name` as a `parameter`? Something like this.

```
@Query("SELECT id, name from :tableName")
fun getData(tableName: String): List<RandomModel>
```

Comment: why would you want to use multiple tables with the same structure (the same type and number of the columns) at all? instead use one table with the extra field that identifies your subset of rows

Comment: represents different business models and there has different properties from each other. I just want to get the common properties.

Comment: @pskink this is super common, e.g. look at CRM software (Salesforce, for example) - pretty much every record has an iD and a representation of a 'name'.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@Dao
interface RawDao {
 @RawQuery
 List<RandomModel> getData(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
}

 SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tablename);
 List<RandomModel> models = rawDao.getUserViaQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `Room` does not support dynamic `tableName`.

We have two ways:

1-In `DAO`, we can replace `tableName` with the actual table name, as defined on the model `@Entity`

2-We can use `@RawQuery` like this :

```
@Dao
 interface RawDao {
     @RawQuery
     User getUserViaQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
 }
 SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",
         new Object[]{userId});
 User user2 = rawDao.getUserViaQuery(query);
```

**You can study more at** [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery.html)

Answer (score 0):

you first create in your Dao a @RawQuery. just Class1, Class2, etc with the tables/classes that you are interested to monitor.

```
@RawQuery(  observedEntities = [Class1::class, CLass2::class]  )
fun query(query:SupportSqliteQuery): List<RandomModel>
```

To use it just create a SimpleSqliteQuery with the  necessary input argument.

note there is a difference between "SupportSqlite..." used in Dao and "SimpleSqlite..." used in the doQuery() function

```
fun doQuery(tableName:String):List<RandomModel> {

    //note $ sign in front of tableName instead of : sign
    val simpleSqliteQuery =  SimpleSqliteQuery("SELECT id, name from $tableName") 
    return dao().query( simpleSqliteQuery  )
}
```