# Android Room: Dynamically deciding on what tables to search

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a Room Database with a Questions-Table and multiple Answer-Tables (with different kind of answers, like Multiple Choice etc).

I want to query multiple Questions and their corresponding Answers. Each Question has an attribute "type" that tells me what Table contains its Answers.

Would it be more efficient to look through all Answer-Tables or use 2 Queries, one to get the Questions and then a Query that searches the correct Answer-Table, based on the type-attribute? I assume some of the Answer-tables could get around 10s to 100s of entries.

Alternatively, could I somehow decide on which Answer-Table to search in the Query itself (based on the type-attribute)?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM questions_table WHERE dataSet = :dataSetId")
    LiveData<List<QuestionWithAnswers>> getQuestionsWithAnswers(int dataSetId);
```

```
public class QuestionWithAnswers extends Question {
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "question")
    public List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> mcAnswers;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "question")
    public NumberRangeAnswer rangeAnswer;
}
```

This would search both Tables (MultipleChoiceAnswer and NumberRangeAnswer) but only one would ever actually contain values. My question is if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room Fetch data with dynamic table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764603/android-room-fetch-data-with-dynamic-table-name)

Comment: Sadly not. 

`@Query("SELECT * FROM questions_table WHERE dataSet = :dataSetId")
    LiveData<List<Question>> getQuestionsForDataSet(int dataSetId);`

This is my query, but instead of only the "Question" I want to return all corresponding Answers as well (via a @Relation). So I could either define multiple relations, searching all tables and in turn leaving all but 1 empty (since only 1 has the corresponding answers) or I could query the Questions first, get the type, then get the answers from the correct Table through the type-parameter of the Question.

Comment: The later seems to be a good option, from the perspective of coding involved, so go with querying the question table first for the answer type and then search within the desired answer-table. The link above explains how to do that